# Can I use @MockBean to mock a bean in just one method of my test class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I have this mvc test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Resource
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private UserBO userBO;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
// ...
    }
// ...
```

**In one single test case I need to mock another bean to cover a special error handling branch. Is this possible? Is there any method I can use which does the same as `@MockBean` for the `UserBO`?** (`PermissionBO` is not retuned by `UserBO` but used on the same level as `UserBO` in the class under test.)

```
@Test(expects=IllegalStatusException.class)
public void testErrorHandlingBranch() {
    // How can I mock the bean *PermissionsBO* only for this test?
    // like @MockBean PermissionsBO permissionsBO;
    // Is there a method like injectMockBean(PermissionsBO.class)?
    mockMvc.perform(...)
}
```

Comment: You should probably try with `thenCallRealMethod` globally and actually mock the method in this one test. Read more here: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.6/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks

Answer (score -4):

You should use `thenReturn()` inside your test method in the way to use a specific mocked value only inside a specific test.

For example:
`Mockito.when(userBO.example()).thenReturn("Specific test method mock");`

Comment: Thanks, but the PermissionBO is not returned from userBO. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you need to do. If `PermissionBO` is at the same level as `UserBO` than probably you need to mock also `PermissionBO`.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely wrong. There is no reason why `PermissionBO` was not yet mocked completely in this class!

Comment: This is not the right answer. This wont make it work perfectly.